# text file fill into two partial fill arrays with different data type C#

Tags: c#

this text file has 8 names and 8 numbers staggered. I have to assume that I have no idea how many strings are in the text file, I only know there are numbers and text i need.

how do I create a void method to extract them into 2 different arrays.
while both array subscript store the values from subscript 0.

This is what i have so far... but it is not right as I already know they are staggered so I'm retrieving every 2 elements.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            const int SIZE = 20;     //set maximum of 20 elements in each array

            string [] nameArray = new string[SIZE];

            double[] voteArray = new double[SIZE];

            double[] percentArray = new double[SIZE];

            InputValue(ref nameArray, ref voteArray);

        }

 private void InputValue(ref string[] aArray, ref double[] bArray)
        {
            int count = 0;
            int SIZE = 20;     //set maximum of 20 elements in each array
            string[] total = new string[SIZE];

            StreamReader inputFile;

            inputFile = File.OpenText("data.txt");

            while(count < total.Length && !inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {

                total[count] = inputFile.ReadLine();
                count ++;

            }

            inputFile.Close();

            for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
            {
              aArray[index] = total[index];

            }

            for (int index = 1; index < count + 1; index += 2)
            {
                bArray[index] = double.Parse(total[index]);

            }

        }
```

Comment: Show us your sample file and its expected output please.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? Check if the element is a number when extracting.

```
int aIndex = 0; // index for array a, the strings array
int bIndex = 0; // have a separate index for array b, we'll call this the numbers array

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if(Char.isNumber(total[i]))
    {
         bArray[bIndex] = double.Parse(total[i]); // add the number to array b
         bIndex++; // increment the b index
    }
    else
    {
         aArray[aIndex] = total[i]; // add char to array a
         aIndex++; // increment the a index
    }
}
```

At the end of the for loop, you should have iterated all the way through `total`, and have two arrays; one with chars and one with numbers both started at index 0. I think that's what you wanted...